# Calculating memory space occupied by unordered maps

Tags: c++, memory-management, unordered-map

I have two unordered maps: (code is executed in linux)

**First unordered map:**

It consists of more atleast 65536 entries. Each entry consists of

```
int
unsigned char
unsigned char
```

**Second unordered map:**

It consists of less than 65536 enteries. Each entry consist of

```
int
int
int
vector <char>
```

Now I want to make comparison of the two on the basis of memory occupied by the above two unordered maps (in bytes). After that I want to calculate memory compression achieved.
Please guide me how can I find the memory occupied by the two unordered maps?

**More details of the second unordered map:**

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int> key_t;

struct KeyHasher
{
  std::size_t operator()(const key_t& k) const
  {
      using boost::hash_value;
      using boost::hash_combine;

      // Start with a hash value of 0    .
      std::size_t seed = 0;

      // Modify 'seed' by XORing and bit-shifting in
      // one member of 'Key' after the other:
      hash_combine(seed,hash_value(std::get<0>(k)));
      hash_combine(seed,hash_value(std::get<1>(k)));

      // Return the result.
      return seed;
  }
};

struct Ndata
{
int value;
vector<char> accept ;
};

typedef boost::unordered_map<const key_t,Ndata,KeyHasher> SecondMap;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "after that I want to calculate memory compression achieved" - what does that mean?

Comment: @MatsPetersson  Basically one unordered map is expected to occupy lesser space as compared to other and this is what I want. But how much less space one occupying with respect to other in terms of bytes that I want to calculate.

Comment: Aside from the fact that we can't tell you how much overhead there is (which is up to the individual implementation), we also don't understand how one translates into the other...

Comment: I have two algorithms. Both of them builds an unordered map. The first algo creates a large number of entries and the second algo is to represent the same thing with less number of entries. I want to calculate the memory usage of the two objects individually.

Comment: And how many more/less is there? You are just saying that there is > 64K or < 64K. There is a huge number of alternatives there. Also, how long (on average) is the vector<char>?

Comment: Depends on the input but for one of my inputs the results were: First unordered map= 65536 entries , second unordered map=526 entries. Vector<char> total number of entries will always be 65536.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to answer your question precisely without looking at the precise `unordered_map` implementation your STL uses.

However, based on the [`unordered_map` interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), you could make decent educated guesses:

An `unordered_map` needs to store:

- one `bucket` container (probably a vector-like structure)
- `max_bucket_count` buckets (probably singly-linked-list-like structures)
- one complete entry for each item (not only the value, but also the key, to handle key hash collisions)

After a quick look at the Libc++ implementation, you also need space to store:

- The hashing function object
- The equality test function object
- The allocator function object

With this in mind, my guesstimate would be something like:

```
typedef unordered_map<K, V, ...> tMyMap;

size_t getMemoryUsage(const tMyMap& map) {
  auto entrySize = sizeof(K) + sizeof(V) + sizeof(void*);
  auto bucketSize = sizeof(void*);
  auto adminSize = 3 * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(size_t);

  auto totalSize = adminSize + map.size() * entrySize + map.max_bucket_count() * bucketSize();
  return totalSize;
}
```

This would only work for the first of your cases, since in the second cases, each entry can have a completely different memory usage based on how big each vector is. For the second case, you would therefore have to add something like this:

```
size_t getMemoryUsage(const tMyMap& map) {
  auto entrySize = sizeof(K) + sizeof(V) + sizeof(void*);
  auto bucketSize = sizeof(void*);
  auto adminSize = 3 * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(size_t);
  auto totalSize = adminSize + map.size() * entrySize + map.max_bucket_count() * bucketSize();

  auto contentSize = 0;
  for (const auto& kv : map) {
    // since accept is a vector<char>, 
    // it uses capacity() bytes of additional memory
    contentSize += kv.second.accept.capacity();
  }
  totalSize += contentSize;

  return totalSize;
}
```

However, considering real-world allocation logic, the memory your map actually uses may differ a lot from this due to e.g. external fragmentation. If you want to be 100% sure how much memory an unordered_map uses, you need to also take allocator behavior into account.

Comment: I have added the details of my second boost::unordered map. Can you please let me know that how would I compute the memory usage for that.

Comment: Secondly, can you please explain why are you adding sizeof(void*) in computing memory usage?

Comment: In the entry size computation, I add the size of a pointer to account for the fact that map entries are actually singly-linked list nodes, so each entry has a pointer to the next entry.

Comment: Alright. One more thing what is adminsize representing? Please elaborate about allocator behaviour and is this necessary to include it?

Comment: adminSize is used to represent the 3 function pointers for the allocator, the equality comparison and the hashing function. After checking in the libc++ implementation, it turns out that there are member variables for these. About allocator behavior: the point I was trying to make was that fragmentation and other allocation behaviors may result in a memory usage that's higher than the memory strictly needed to represent your data. If you want to be really precise, you should just check how your STL implementation does it.

Answer (score 2):

One *possible* approach is to find out by experiment using custom allocators.

A straight forward solution could leverage C++11's "Scoped allocator model" (see also [The Scoped Allocator Model (Rev 2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf), [Stroustrup: Scoped allocators](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#scoped-allocator). A "scoped allocator" will be applied to the container and *recursively* to its elements.

Providing such a custom allocator for the `std::unordered_map` and its elements would enable you to *precisely* count the number of blocks, it's size and the total amount.

By the way, a scoped allocator would also let you optimize the memory consumption and performance, for example by providing an "arena allocator".

There's just one caveat: Despite the Scoped Allocator Model is required by C+11 conformance, it's likely that's it's not implemented in the standard library provided by the Compiler vendor. For example, clang's standard library fully implements Scoped allocators for all containers. Regarding GCC, please read here: [GCC Status](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html), and the GCC mailing list.

**Edit:**

A completely different approach is to use a *tool* which analyses the memory consumption. For example, the Xcode IDE provides an excellent tool "Instruments", which provides various analysis methods, one for tracking heap and object allocations. It would take just seconds to compare your two different versions. The available tools will differ for your platform, of course ;)

Comment: Is there any other profiling tool which can help me to calculate memory usage of objects in linux? Because I have never worked with allocators before and I have not find any easy example yet to make use of allocators in my code.

Comment: @Zara There is a wide range of profiling tools available, e.g. DTrace, [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) and perf to name a few. The malloc library may also provide some debugging aids (see man malloc_history). Then, there are third party tools like igProf (see igprof.org) and many others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an array containing your maps. 
You will be able to create lots of them (e.g. 10 thousands) You can then divide the total memory (as indicated by the OS) by 10 thousand. Of couse you would need to take the overhead (memory consumption before allocating your maps) into account (including the array).

Doing lots of sizeof would not help, because for each allocation on the heap, you have an implementation defined overhead. For example on Visual Studio 2013, in Release allocations are done by multiple of 8 bytes (or 16 bytes for large arrays).